# Files and values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, elasticsearch, python-3.6

the below query is reading from a file called number.txt and prints out the numbers.

i want to some how read the number.txt file and then run a update curl query against the numbers in the txt file.

the query for reading the file

```
f = open('number.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
f.close()
```

this is the update curl query, as you can i want to update the color to red.

so i want to read the number txt file which contains ID and then updated the colour against those ID to red.

curl query

```
 coll.update(index='stories-test',doc_type='news',id=hit.meta.id,
                body={"doc": {"colour": red }})
```

number.txt (this contains ID for unique people)

```
20170512 

20170512  

20170908  

20170908
```

anyone able to help and show me how to do this.

thanks

Comment: You need to show the content of the `number.txt` file

Comment: i have edited the original post. @val thank you for taking a look. i hope my post makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to read the file line by line and then iterate over each line and make your update call, like this

```
for id in open('number.txt', 'r').read().splitlines():
     if id.strip():
         coll.update(index = 'stories-test', doc_type = 'news', id = id,
                    body={"doc": {"colour": "red" }})
```

Comment: thank you, but i think its failing due to this error - .NotFoundError: TransportError(404, 'document_missing_exception', '[news][20170512 \n]: document missing'). is that because the code does not support spaces as the number.txt ID's is in a list? how do i add in the code to support /n?

Comment: Hmm, you either need to remove the empty lines or make sure that the id is not a blank string. See my updated answer

Comment: that worked, thanks Val. i have upvoted you and made your answer as correct.